# how to get the Client id of a listbox using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a Listbox in asp.net i am trying to get the client id of Listbox but i am getting `[object Object]` in alert

```
<asp:ListBox ID="drpJobStatus" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
```

```js
alert($("#<%= drpJobStatus.ClientID %>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is because you're alerting the jQuery object itself.

However you don't need any jQuery code to achieve what you need as you already have the `ClientId` within the string from ASP:

```
alert('<%= drpJobStatus.ClientID %>');
```

> how to alert it's value? I want to see its value

In that case you need to use the `val()` method on the jQuery object:

```
alert($('#<%= drpJobStatus.ClientID %>').val());
```

Also note that you should really be using `console.log()` for debugging as it does not coerce datatypes as `alert()` does.

Comment: how to alert ot's value i want to see ti's value

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use **$("#<%= drpJobStatus.ClientID %>")[0].id**. Explanation in attached pic above.